# Is it possible to discover the sender of a signal using new style pyqtSignal?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

Given the following code as an example I would like to know whether the `receiver()` function is able to discover whether w1 or w2 sent it the signal?

Obviously I know that I could package this information into the message sent in the signal but I want to know whether it's available without doing this. As far as I can tell the `sender()` function is not available to the receiver.

```py
import sys, time, random
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Worker(QThread):
    jobDone = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        print 'new Worker'
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2) # give time for event loop to start
        print 'thread working'
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,8))
        self.jobDone.emit('job done')

class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w1 = Worker()
        self.w1.jobDone.connect(self.receiver)

        self.w2 = Worker()
        self.w2.jobDone.connect(self.receiver)

        self.w1.start()
        self.w2.start()

    def receiver(self, msg):
        print msg

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Manager()
    print 'before event loop'
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sender()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#sender) method is available to all classes derived from `QObject`, but your `Manager` class isn't a subclass of `QObject`.

If you want to use `sender()` in your class, just meake it inherit from `QObject`.

Comment: Ok but is there an equivalent way of identifying the sender for classes not derived from `QObject`?

Comment: I've just tried it, and it seems to work if you call the `sender()` method on any `QObject`, I'm just not really sure if it's safe to do so (specially in multitheraded applications). See the warnings in the documentation.